# need help in queues insertion of 10 names

Tags: c++, queue

I've just started learning queues using c++ .im required to add 10 names, display them, then remove them, then redisplay the names, I've attempted to do so, but im getting error "operator = is ambiguous". kindly help.
i dont know where i went wrong.i know we are suppose to add 10 names then pass them in insertion()
then we should remove the string in queue
then after displaying it should return all 0s

'''

```
template<class t>
class Queue
{
private:
int front;
int rear;
t arr[10];

public:
Queue()
{
    front = -1;
    rear = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
}
int isEmpty()
{
    if (front == -1 && rear == -1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int isFull() 
{
    if (rear == 9)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
void insertion(t value)
{
    if (isFull()==1)
    {
        cout << "Cant be inserted ,Queue full" << endl;
        
    }
    else if (isEmpty()==1) 
    {
        front = 0;
        rear = 0;
        arr[rear] = value;
    }
    else 
    {
        rear++;
        arr[rear] = value;
    }

}

t deletion()
{
    t x ;
    if (isEmpty()==1) 
    {
        cout << "Cant be deleted ,Queue is Empty" << endl;
        return x;
    }
    else if (rear == front) 
    {
        x = arr[rear];
        rear = -1;
        front = -1;
        return x;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "front value: " << front << endl;
        x = arr[front];
        arr[front] = 0;
        front++;
        return x;
    }
}

int count()
{
    return (rear - front + 1);
}

void display()
{
    cout << "All values in the Queue are - " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }
  }

  };

int main() {
Queue < string> q1;
int value, option;

string name;
cout << "Enter 10 names";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cin >> name;
    q1.insertion(name);

}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    
    q1.deletion();

}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    
    q1.insertion(name);

}

return 0;
}'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're generalizing the Queue, you can't initiate the values to 0. The ambiguity comes from the fact the compiler doesn't know if 0 refers to the numerical value 0 or to the ASCII equivalent to 0 (i'm not sure if I'm verbalizing this properly, but it's what it's happening).

You can circumvent this by setting it to '\0' - the array terminator character - instead of 0. If the array is numeric it'll evaluate to 0, if the array is alphanumeric it'll act as NULL. I'm assuming your intention is initializing an empty array, so this would solve the problem.

```
Queue(){
    front = -1;
    rear = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        arr[i] = '\0';
    }
}
```

You could also do this instead of the for loop, since your array size is constant:

```
template<class t>
class Queue{
    private:
    int front;
    int rear;
    t arr[10] = {'\0'};
}
Queue(){
    front = -1;
    rear = -1;
}
```

Some suggestions I feel are in order:

- Consider using a vector instead of an array. By using a vector the compiler won't complain about the 0 thing, since the structure handles that, and your class becomes more versatile
- If you don't want to use a vector - gotta respecc the hard route - consider implementing dynamic memory allocation using malloc and realloc. While a bit harder to figure out at first, that's how arrays end up being used in this type of context. This allows you to set the array size to be as big as you want, increasing it and decreasing it as needed (kinda like a vector ;) )
- Consider adding a size parameter to the constructor. This will make your class more versatile, and will allow you to peek into how STL Queue is implemented. You could also drop the size altogether and modify your insertion method to allocate more memory as needed

These types of implementations are great learning exercises and always bring up a bunch of weird challenges and problems. I hope the answer helps!

Comment: thank you so much for such an amazing reply! okay so ive made these changes and i think my code runs well, i have a tiny doubt tho. in int main ive made these changes

Comment: 'int main() {
    Queue < string> q1;
    int value, option;

    string name;
    cout << "Enter 10 names"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> name;
        q1.insertion(name);

    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        q1.deletion();


    }
        

    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        q1.display();


    }
    


    return 0;
}'

Comment: here my deletion loop isnt working  as when i display names after deleting, it still displays a weird pattern of alphabets

Comment: @codeplayer after deleting a name you have to update the array termination character ('\0'). Upon display, you can use something like
```
for(int i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++)
```
There are better ways to write this, but this one works. What it does is that the array will print until the loop finds the terminator character. This way you don't get random garbage values printed out